# Subquery with sum function to pull in multiple records

Tags: oracle11g

SubQuery pulling in the same record in the "ON_ORDER" column. I want the query to pull in the ON_ORDER qty per Item. Can someone please show me what I am not doing right? I have been on this for quite awhile.

```
SELECT
N.SITEID,
C.LOCATION,
(I.EX2AREARESP||I.EX2STDSTS||I.EX2APPTYPE) AS STD,
I.ITEMNUM,
I.COMMODITY,
I.COMMODITYGROUP,
I.DESCRIPTION,
I.ISSUEUNIT,
C.AVGCOST,
SUM(NVL(B.CURBAL,0)) AS CURBAL,
NVL(SUM(D.SHIPPEDQTY),0) AS IN_TRANSIT,
(
SELECT

SUM(PL.ORDERQTY - NVL(PL.RECEIVEDQTY,0))

FROM MSCRADS.PO P,
     MSCRADS.POLINE PL,
     MXRADS.ITEM I


WHERE P.PONUM =  PL.PONUM
AND PL.LINETYPE = 'ITEM'
AND P.RECEIPTS <> 'COMPLETE'
AND PL.ITEMNUM = I.ITEMNUM
AND P.ORDERDATE >= TO_DATE('2014/05/26','YYYY/MM/DD')
AND PL.RECEIPTSCOMPLETE = '0'
AND P.INTERNAL = '0'
AND PL.ISSUE = '0'
AND P.STATUS NOT IN ('COMPLETE','CLOSE','CAN')
AND P.SITEID <> 'MS'



AND P.REVISIONNUM = PL.REVISIONNUM    
AND (P.HISTORYFLAG = '0' OR (P.HISTORYFLAG = '1' 
AND P.STATUS = 'CLOSE' AND PL.RECEIVEDQTY > '0'))
AND NOT (P.STATUS = 'COMPLETE' 
AND (PL.RECEIVEDQTY = '0' OR PL.RECEIVEDQTY IS NULL))
) AS "ON_ORDER",  


NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN D.RESTYPE = 'APSOFT' THEN D.RESERVEDQTY 
    ELSE NULL END),0) AS "ALLOCATED",
NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN D.RESTYPE = 'APHARD' THEN D.RESERVEDQTY 
    ELSE NULL END),0) AS "RESERVE", 
N.MINLEVEL AS ROP,
N.ORDERQTY AS EOQ,
N.DELIVERYTIME AS LEADTIME,
NVL(N.SSTOCK,0)  "SAFETY STOCK",
CASE N.REORDER WHEN 1 THEN 'AUTO_RE-ORDER'
               WHEN 0 THEN 'MANUAL_RE-ORDER'
               ELSE ' ' 
               END AS "REORDER PROCESS",
N.STATUS "INVENTORY STATUS"


FROM MXRADS.INVENTORY N

LEFT OUTER JOIN
MXRADS.ITEM I
ON I.ITEMNUM = N.ITEMNUM

LEFT OUTER JOIN
MSCRADS.INVCOST C
ON N.ITEMNUM = C.ITEMNUM
AND N.LOCATION = C.LOCATION

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
MSCRADS.INVBALANCES B
ON N.ITEMNUM = B.ITEMNUM
AND N.LOCATION = B.LOCATION

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
MSCRADS.INVRESERVE D
ON N.ITEMNUM = D.ITEMNUM
AND N.LOCATION = D.LOCATION 



WHERE N.SITEID <> 'MS'
AND N.LOCATION = '&WHSE'
AND N.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
--AND N.ITEMNUM = '505611'

GROUP BY
N.SITEID,
C.LOCATION,
(I.EX2AREARESP||I.EX2STDSTS||I.EX2APPTYPE),
I.ITEMNUM,
I.COMMODITY,
I.COMMODITYGROUP,
I.DESCRIPTION,
I.ISSUEUNIT,
C.AVGCOST,
N.MINLEVEL,
N.ORDERQTY,
N.DELIVERYTIME,
N.SSTOCK,
N.REORDER,
N.STATUS


ORDER BY 4
```

Comment: You didn't connect the main query and the subquery did is why you always get the same result. Try to remove this join in the subquery "MXRADS.ITEM I"

Comment: So I have have connected the subquery  to main query as below but it takes forever to run.

Comment: It runs a subquery for every row of the main select so it can be slow. You can try to join MSCRADS.PO and MSCRADS.POLINE in the main select if it is doable and make the ON_ORDER expression without the subquery, this would speed up the query substantially.